# Best and Secure way to upload file using php

Tags: php, upload

This is my first Question on Stackoverflow.

I spend my many hour on google to find what is the most secure way to upload file in PHP. there i found some techniques like check file extension, rename file or many other, so kindly tell me if there are any other options for same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is already asked here. 
but you can use my own code for same it is simple and secure.

```
function hc_upload($f,$username='',$verify_type=1,$size=2048)
{
    $f=$_FILES[$f];
    $file_name=strtolower($f['name']);
    $file_type=strtolower($f['type']);
    $file_size=strtolower($f['size']);
    $file_extenstion =end(explode('.',$file_name));
    $file_extenstion2=strtolower(pathinfo(basename($file_name),PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

    if($file_extenstion2!=$file_extenstion){
        $err["error"]=true;
        $err["message"]="Invalid file extension.";
        return $err;
    }
    if($file_size > $size*1000){
        $err["error"]=true;
        $err["message"]="File is too large.";
        return $err;
    }

    $ext_verify=0;
    if(gettype($verify_type)!='array')
    {
        $verify_type=(string)$verify_type;
        if((strpos($verify_type,"1") > -1 || $verify_type=="*") &&  $ext_verify==0)
        {
            $mimes['ext']=array("jpg","jpeg","gif","png");
            $mimes['mime']=array("image/jpg","image/jpeg","image/gif","image/png");
            if(in_array($file_extenstion,$mimes['ext']) && in_array($file_type,$mimes['mime'])){$ext_verify=1;}
        }
        if((strpos($verify_type,"2") > -1 || $verify_type=="*") &&  $ext_verify==0)
        {
            $mimes['ext']=array("doc","docx","pdf","xls","xlsx","ppt","pptx");
            if(in_array($file_extenstion,$mimes['ext'])){$ext_verify=1;}
        }

        if((strpos($verify_type,"3") > -1 || $verify_type=="*") &&  $ext_verify==0)
        {
            $mimes['ext']=array("mp3","wav","weba","3gp","mp4","mov","mpeg","avi");
            $mimes['mime']=array("audio/mpeg","audio/wav","audio/webm","audio/3gpp","video/3gpp","video/mp4","video/quicktime","video/mpeg","video/x-msvideo");
            if(in_array($file_extenstion,$mimes['ext']) && in_array($file_type,$mimes['mime'])){$ext_verify=1;}
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if(array_key_exists("mime",$verify_type) && array_key_exists("ext",$verify_type)){
            if(in_array($file_extenstion,$verify_type['ext']) && in_array($file_type,$verify_type['mime'])){$ext_verify=1;}
        }
        elseif(array_key_exists("ext",$verify_type)){
            if(in_array($file_extenstion,$verify_type['ext'])){$ext_verify=1;}
        }
        elseif(array_key_exists("mime",$verify_type)){
            if(in_array($file_type,$verify_type['mime'])){$ext_verify=1;}
        }
        else{
            if(in_array($file_extenstion,$verify_type)){$ext_verify=1;}
        }
    }

    if($ext_verify==0){
        $err["error"]=true;
        $err["message"]="Seems your file is not valid";
        return $err;
    }

    $upload_dir='upload/'.$username.'/';
    if(!is_dir($upload_dir)){
        if(!mkdir($upload_dir,0777,true)){
            $err["error"]=true;
            $err["message"]="Unknown error, kindly contact admin";
            return $err;
        }
    }

    $upload_file=$upload_dir.sha1_file($f['tmp_name']);
    if(!file_exists($upload_file)){
        if(!move_uploaded_file($f['tmp_name'], $upload_file)){
            $err["error"]=true;
            $err["message"]="Unknown error, kindly contact admin";
            return $err;
        }
    }

    $err["error"]=true;
    $err["message"]="SUCCESS";
    $err["dir"]=$upload_file;
    return $err;
}
```

And HTML Sample Code is

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>
```

So simply call this function in php

`hc_upload('fileToUpload','',123)`
you can create folder for each username by giving value two second parameter
and third parameter two check for file is image or document or audio/video media and also can pass array of extensions for manually check